# 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'name'

Tags: tensorflow2.0, language-features

After following this tutorial (https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/feature_columns) I am trying to repeat it in Colab with my own data. I follow step by step but by the end, I reach this error and I can't find any explanation about it

```
[NumericColumn(key='GR', shape=(1,), default_value=None, dtype=tf.float32, normalizer_fn=None),
 NumericColumn(key='ILD_log10', shape=(1,), default_value=None, dtype=tf.float32, normalizer_fn=None),
 NumericColumn(key='DeltaPHI', shape=(1,), default_value=None, dtype=tf.float32, normalizer_fn=None),
 NumericColumn(key='PHIND', shape=(1,), default_value=None, dtype=tf.float32, normalizer_fn=None),
 NumericColumn(key='PE', shape=(1,), default_value=None, dtype=tf.float32, normalizer_fn=None),
 IndicatorColumn(categorical_column=array([3, 2, 8, 6, 7, 4, 5, 9, 1])),
 IndicatorColumn(categorical_column=array([3, 2, 8, 6, 7, 4, 5, 9, 1]))]
```

and trying to apply

```
feature_layer = tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures(feature_columns)
```

this is the error I Get:

Comment: Hi Gonzalo.  I think you forgot to include your error string.  All the same, the likely distinction is that the shape of your data does not match the shape of the data in the tutorial.  You may want to give that a check.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and sorry on the delay...I was on vacationes! The error is: